# nodejs chat example does not work

Tags: mongodb, node.js, serverside-javascript

I've come across a node chat example on github, When I try to run it, I see the following error:

> Error connecting to mongo perhaps it isn't running ?

I've installed mongo 0.9.2, nodejs 5.2 pre, npm 3.0 and other dependencies. The example can be found here: https://github.com/gregstewart/chat.io

I can not determine whether if the example not really works or I didn't run it right. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install and start [mongo-db](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) on your system? This error is mostly because of a missing mongo instance running on the local machine.

Check out the follwing code excerpts from chat.io.

main.js:

```
/**
* Configure the user provider (mongodB connection for user data storage)
*/
var userProvider = new UserProvider('localhost', 27017);
```

Creates a new UserProvider object using host and port for database (localhost:27017, mongo-db default).

UserProvider.js:

```
UserProvider = function(host, port) {
    this.db = new mongo.Db('node-mongo-chat', new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
    this.db.addListener('error', function(error) {
      console.log('Error connecting to mongo -- perhaps it isn\'t running?');
    });
    this.db.open(function() {
    });
};
```

Opening the connection to the server, printing out an error on failure (the error you mentioned above).

Consider reading up on the mongo-db docs concerning installation and setup [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart)

Comment: I installed mongodb by doing in the terminal $ npm install mongodb. How can I start it ? Have you run the example does it work for you?

Comment: mongo-db is not a node module, you just installed the driver. You have to install the database server available at http://www.mongodb.org in order to use the driver.

Comment: @runrunforest you need to install mongodb and then follow the [quickstart](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix)